# In android how to get which compiled version(compiled with(library file version)) they used in the project from apk file

Tags: android, eclipse

In android how to get which compiled version((compiled with)(library file version)) They  used in the project By using  .apk file

I decompiled the apk and check it. But i can,t able know that.
In AndroidManifest.xml They didn't mentioned like "android:minSdkVersion" and "android:targetSdkVersion".That's Why i am asked this question

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

.apk is just a simple archive file. You can open it with [WinRar](http://rarlabs.com/) for example and find the `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside that archive and you should have a line that starts with `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion`. The former is what's the oldest version of Android that the application supports and the latter is the target devices i.e. the version of SDK that compiled the code.

Comment: Thank you for Quick Replay.In AndroidManifest.xml They didn't mentioned like "AndroidManifest.xml" and "android:targetSdkVersion".That's Why i am asked this question.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your question :(

Comment: To NitroNbg.       I have an one apk file.I need to know which library file version(That means at the time of creating project which type of "compiled with" they given)